# "Creation team" or "creative team"

Tags: word-choice

In a text about videogames I was requested to form a term from the verb *create* in this context.

> Time is running out on the production of this videogame. The game's
>   **creation/creative team** must be feeling the pressure.

I've been discussing the two expressions with my family and we haven't reached an agreement. I would choose *creative* but I'm not sure.

Comment: Does the sentence refer to the creative people?  The artists and possibly the writers, or does it refer to the software developers and project managers too?

Comment: from the whole text, I gather it refers to software developers only

Comment: Then I would go with **development** instead.

Comment: I would do so too, if I had the choice. Unfortunately, it was a word formation exercise, so I must stick to the original term to be used, that is "create".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would definitely go with creative.  My reason is that "creative" is an adjective and "creation" is a noun, so it just sounds better.

Comment: +1 because it answers the question of deciding between the two alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

google results

- creative team     552,000,000
- creation team     196,000,000
- "creative team"    8,930,000
- "creation team"    187,000

Personally, I've never heard people talk about the creation team.

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard "creation team". Further, it brings to mind polytheistic pantheons as opposed to groups of programmers and game designers. ;)

You could say "content-creation team" or "creative team", but those are different things, the "content-creation team" filling some large data structure with information (this includes guys who work for Google Maps, journals, writers, poets, journalists, even *bloggers* could be understood to be content creation), whereas a "creative team" comes up with new ideas.

But, as Joshua Drake noted in the comments on the question, "development team" is a better name, because it describes the whole process, whereas a "creative team" only describes the initial idea-generation, which is a single step in the development process.